# Best Practice when trying to conditionally render a styled component inside or outside of wrapper based on screen width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I have this code. I am trying to figure how best to have the code conditionally put inside our outside of the wrapper. But I am not sure what is the best practice for this.

But that seems a little undry. Is there a better practice than this? Thanks!

But that seems

Answer (score 0):

In render, store the JSX of the thing you need to move around in a variable and then use that in the same way you did in the last method you mentioned.

```
const overlay = (
  <CTAButton
    colorStyle={el.ctaColor === "green" ? "green" : "black"}
    href={el?.cta?.link}
  >
    {el?.cta?.text}
  </CTAButton>
);

// ...

return (
  <>
    <Styled.OverlayWrapper>
      {el.headline && (
        <Styled.HeroHeadline as="h4">{parse(el.headline)}</Styled.HeroHeadline>
      )}
      {screenWidth <= 600 && overlay}
    </Styled.OverlayWrapper>
    {screenWidth >= 601 && overlay}
  </>
);
```

Though I should add, usually with this sort of thing, it can be solved with CSS breakpoints without DOM changes needed -- which is preferable. But that'd be an entirely different question.

Notably it can't always be solved that way depending on the circumstances of the desired layout. The above could be fine in your use case.